# sql get data where date is greater than current month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dateadd

i want to retrieve records where a date field is set to future months

does this look correct

```
Select * from table1 WHERE
 datesetto >MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select * from tablename where month(columndate)>month(getdate()) and 
 year(columndate)>=year(getdate())
```

Comment: But if you for instance use this query in October 2016, it will only take into account Nov-Dec 2016, Nov-Dec 2017, Nov-Dec 2018 and so on. I do not think that was the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE datesetto >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())+1, 0)
```

Explanation:

- `DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())` calculates how many months have passed since 1900-01-01.
- `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)` returns the beginning of this month.
- `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate())+1, 0)` returns the beginning of next month.

Comment: It helps me a lot .Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
  Select * from table1 WHERE
  ((DATEPART(MONTH,datesetto) > DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) 
  AND DATEPART(YEAR,datesetto) = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()))
  OR (DATEPART(YEAR,datesetto) > DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())))
```

`DATEPART(Month,GETDATE())` will give the month of the current date and then you can compare it with the `datesetto`

**Update:** The above query will give data for any months greater than the current month and any month greater in the year than the current year.

Comment: This will return a correct result, but won't it be slow because it can not take advantage of an index over datesetto?